# Negative reputation doesn't show on the mini-graph in the profile

Tags: support, notifications, reputation-graph

I got +60 reputation on 2nd June 2016. On 3rd June 2016, I got -60 reputation, because of the reversal.

The +60 is shown on the mini-graph in the profile, but -60 isn't. Here are two snapshots to make it clear.

[image: shown in the reputation tab]

[image: not shown on the mini-graph]

Also, in notifications, the -60 notification is not showing up. Snapshot is attached for reference.

[image: my reputation dropdown doesn't have -60 rep notification]

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is here. Are you asking why this happens? Are you saying this shouldn't happen?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat the title of the question says it all. and also why does it happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is by design. The mini rep-graph shows just positive rep. To see the negative rep also, you click ["graph" in the "reputation" tab](https://stackapps.com/users/33857/amit-jha?tab=reputation&sort=graph).

> [image]

As for no -60 notification in your dropdown - instead of adding this entry, system just removes the reversed votes from it.